# Invisible java bytecode lines

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I am wondering why the line numbers of Java Bytecode are not consecutive.

What happens for example in the (not listed) lines 2 and 3 of the following getter?

```
public java.lang.String getX();

Code:
0:   aload_0
1:   getfield        #2; //Field x:Ljava/lang/String;
4:   areturn
```

I'm using the ASM framework to work on bytecode. When visiting the code of a method using the tree API I get these "hidden" instructions as well (however with opcode -1). I would like to know what they are for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think that `0, 1, 4` are linenumbers but byte offsets in the bytecode.

- `aload_0` is one byte
- `getfield` is three bytes (one opcode, one "index" arg with two bytes"
- `areturn` is one byte

So `2` and `3` are simply part of the `getfield` operation.

Comment: Thank you. What about the additional instructions ASM provided me with?

Comment: You say "however with opcode -1". Therefore I guess, this means "not an instruction".  If the data you get is `0x00` and `0x02` the my guess is correct, you see the `#2` argument of `getfield`.

Answer (score 4):

A little explanation

The size of the array of local variables is determined at compile time and is dependent on the number and size of local variables and formal method parameters. The operand stack is a LIFO stack used to push and pop values. Its size is also determined at compile time. Certain opcode instructions push values onto the operand stack; others take operands from the stack, manipulate them, and push the result. The operand stack is also used to receive return values from methods.

```
public String getBar(){ 
    return bar; 
  }

  public java.lang.String getBar();
    Code:
      0:   aload_0
      1:   getfield        #2; //Field bar:Ljava/lang/String;
      4:   areturn
```

The bytecode for the method above consists of three opcode instructions. The first opcode, aload_0, pushes the value from index 0 of the local variable table onto the operand stack. The this reference is always stored at location 0 of the local variable table for constructors and instance methods. The next opcode instruction, getfield, is used to fetch a field from an object. The last instruction, areturn, returns a reference from a method.

Each method has a corresponding bytecode array. Looking at a .class file with a hex editor, you would see the following values in the bytecode array:

That said, the bytecode for getBar method is 2A B4 00 02 B0. The code 2A corresponds to aload_0 instruction, and B0 corresponds to areturn. It might seem strange that the bytecode of the method has 3 instructions, but the byte array holds 5 elements. This is because the getfield (B4) requires 2 parameters to be supplied (00 02), and those parameters occupy positions 2 and 3 in the array, hence the array size is 5 and areturn instruction is shifted to the position 4.

[Source](http://arhipov.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/java-bytecode-fundamentals.html)

[Java bytecode instruction listings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings)

Comment: Actually getfield takes a single argument, but that argument is two bytes.